# How to pass 'prefix' and parameter to the route in the group (Laravel 7 / 8)?

Tags: laravel, routes

I have next route file:

```
Route::prefix('{?lang}')->where(['lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'])->middleware('locale')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/news/{news}', [App\Http\Controllers\NewsController::class, 'show'])->name('news.show');

});
```

The middleware is:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->method() == 'GET') {
        $segment = $request->segment(1);

        if (!in_array($segment, config('app.locales'))) {
            $segments = $request->segments();
            array_shift($segments);
            $fallback = session('locale') ?: config('app.fallback_locale');
            $segments = Arr::prepend($segments, $fallback);

            return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments));
        }

        session(['locale' => $segment]);
        app()->setLocale($segment);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and if I use route like that (in the *.blade file)

```
<a href='{{ route('home', app()->getLocale()) }}'>
```

I got next address

```
<a href='/en/home/'>
```

But I have parameter which I should pass to the route /news/{news} and if I try next:

```
<a href="{{ route('news.show', ['lang' => app()->getLocale(), 'news' => $new->slug]) }}">
```

I got error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W647.png)

Can somebody help me? I already spent 3 hours with it......

Comment: if you give a default value then what happen ? like `{{ route('news.show', ['lang' => 'en', 'news' => 'a_slug']) }}`

Comment: The same result

Comment: After php artisan commands result didn't changed

I have no idea what I must do...

Answer (score 0):

So,

```
<a href="{{ route('news.show', [app()->getLocale(),$new->slug]) }}">
```

and in the Conrollers' method for this route

```
(string $lang, News $news)
```

in my case it's work